# Android, My EditText wont respect its weight in Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In order to make my view always visible even when the keyboard shows, I made a linear layout and gave every item a weigth. I made the TextViews uniform and gave them a minimum size:

```
app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8dp", app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

as you can see below. However, when I click to edit the `EditText`, everything gets smaller but the EditText will not respect the weigth, even though it has the value `4`, which should make it appear much more than the rest. Also, the little `TextView` disappear almost completely

What is happening?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ChargeActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/receiveCheckbox"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Receber valor automaticamente" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewValueToCharge"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/charge_hint_type_value_with_decimals"
                            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8dp"
                            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editTextValueToCharge"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="4"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:textSize="30sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewPaymentOption"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/charge_label_choose_payment_action_below"
                            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8dp"
                            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/buttonCreditOnly"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="45dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:background="#28a745"
                            android:text="@string/charge_button_credit_only" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/buttonCreditWithInstallments"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="45dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:background="#28a745"
                            android:text="@string/charge_button_charge_credit_with_installments" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/buttonDebit"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="45dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:background="#28a745"
                            android:text="@string/charge_button_charge_debit" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewNumberOfInstallments"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/number_of_installments"
                            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8dp"
                            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinnerNumberOfInstallments"
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            tools:visibility="gone">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textViewProgressBar"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                    android:text="@string/start_connection_terminal"
                                    android:visibility="gone" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textViewResponse"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                    android:text="@string/start_transaction_status"
                                    android:visibility="gone" />

                                <ProgressBar
                                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:visibility="gone" />

                                <Space
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonAction"
                                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/imageViewResponse"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                    android:src="@drawable/icon_denied"
                                    android:tint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                                    android:visibility="gone" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/buttonAction"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="#28a745"
                            android:text="@string/charge_button_pay_label"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you try to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` for your Activity in your AndroidManifresh

Comment: @PhanVanLinh it's already like this. This is what's in the fact resizing. Now I need the EditText to respect the weight I gave it

Comment: Use android:layout_height="0dp" instead of wrap_content in all the children of the LL